# Repositioning rownames and colnames on heatmap in R

Tags: r

I want to get the rownames and colnames of the heatmap on the left and top respectively. By default it puts them on the right and bottom. I tried a lot to find a solution but all in vain.

Note: I am using heatmap.2() function

Thanks,

Akshat

Comment: Looking at the source, it appears that the sides are hard-coded into the function. Perhaps you can just copy the function and reverse it; warning, there are a lot of other things that depend on sidedness, so you'll likely have to recalculate things like `xpos` and `ypos` for various components. (In other words: you might be better off either accepting the sides or finding another way to plot heatmaps.)

Comment: Do you need the dendrograms?

Comment: @d.b no, I don't need dendograms